# Setting local variable of a global function via kwargs in Python

Tags: python

Not being able to overload functions in Python brought me to look into `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass undefined amounts of arguments and variable definitions to a called function. I tried to apply that concept to a simple function that prints arguments to the screen using a seperator (and without the nasty "" around everything by the while). You can find the code snippet at the end of that post.

My problem is that I don't know the correct way to actually assign values of  kwargs to their respective parameters OUTSIDE CLASSES. If I want use `setattr` which takes in 3 arguments (`setatt(self, key, value)`) it will, of course, always give me an error when I try to pass only a key and a value. Is there a proper way to assign values to parameters for global functions outside classes?

I hope you can clear the skies for me.

Here the not working code example which I wanna get to work by finding an alternative to `setattr(self, key, value)`:

```
import sys

def printAll(*args, **kwargs):
    sep = ""
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(key, value)
    for arg in args:
        sys.stdout.write(str(arg))
        sys.stdout.write(sep)

nr = 9876543210
printAll("How many", "arguments", " I want", nr, sep='-')
```

EDIT:
Ok, here is the updated and working example function after reading the answers of @Martijn Pieters and @Fabian:

```
def printAll(*args, **kwargs):
    # use sep = 'value' to define a seperator or use the default one
    sep = kwargs.get('sep')
    if sep is None:
        sep = ""
    for arg in args:
        sys.stdout.write(str(arg))
        sys.stdout.write(sep)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally *don't* set `kwargs` values as local variables. It's a dictionary, just refer to the values contained:

```
sys.stdout.write(kwargs.get('sep', ''))
```

Comment: Ok, now I know what I should do with them actually. Updated my initial post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @FlorianR.Klein: That looks better indeed; use `sep is None` instead (`None` is a singleton, the normal pattern is to test for identity, that test is faster). I've adjusted my example to use an empty string if `sep` is not specified too.

Comment: @MartinjnPieters: Ok, applied the small change too. A slightly better performance for no actual costs (not even if you are lazy at typing) is always good.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        locals()[key] = value
    return foobar
    exec ''

print foo(foobar=12)
```

This is not a good idea though. You should specifically access `kwargs`, as Martijn said. Generally you cannot modify `locals()` in a function, unless you put an `exec` statement in it. That forces the interpreter to access `locals()` again, because it's possible that the namespace has changed (and did, in this case). It's sufficient to put the `exec` statement right after the `return` so it will never be executed, as long as it's there.

Please don't do this.

Comment: This takes me some time to understand but thank you outlining the possibility (and of course that nobody should do something alike :) ).

Comment: This only works because you added `exec ''`. Changes to the `locals()` of a function are normally not reflected. In python 2 you can also do `exec '{} = {!r}'.format(key, value)` to work around that, but using `exec` in a function reduces performance (as optimizations have to be disabled for this to work).

Comment: Generally, *you want to avoid doing this* like the plague. In Python 3, `exec` doesn't work to set function locals anymore.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what do you mean? This works. Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Ah, yes, you added `exec ''` at the end to disable the optimization, in that case modifying `locals()` does work, but the same limitations apply: doesn't work in Python 3, and kills performance as the compiler switches to local-or-global lookup mode instead of fast frame-local mode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, that's why I wrote "Python 2" and "please don't do this" :-) -- thanks for your further explanation.